# pointing domain name to blogger

Tags: dns, hosting, blogger

I have purchased a domain name from a local hoster. 
When I go to may panel it shows the following things. 
[Registered Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dea3v.jpg)

I want my blogger to point here. But I have no idea what to do here.My domain name is `bropoint.com`. Heres what blogger says.
[Blogger Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12sGz.jpg)

Any one could help me with this ? Thank you.

Comment: looks like you are using InMotionHosting. Have you added the Cname correctly?

Comment: I didnt add anywhere nothing.

Comment: @NovoLucas i have no idea at all

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**
 - Depending on your Domain Provider, the process may vary.

**In BlogSpot**
Head over to Settings > Basics and you will see an option which says Publishing >Blog address > + Setup a 3rd party URL for your blog

After adding the domain name, it will give two CNAME records. Once you have these CNAME details, login to your domain control panel.

**If You are Using InMotionHosting**

1. Click the Advanced Zone Editor button in the Domains section.
2. Click the drop-down menu, and choose the domain you want to edit the DNS for.
3. Click the drop-down menu under Type, and choose CNAME.

Add the record like this 
[image: See how the details are entered]

Similarly add the second CNAME also.

You should be able to see both the CNames then.